# Kill nohup process unix

Tags: unix, pid, nohup

I am running jar using nohup command

> nohup java -jar Test.jar

I can't find PID of the jar I am running. I try with:

> ps ax | grep java

but it is not listing, then I tried with

> ps -ef | grep nohup

and I got this output

> root      8503  7529  0 21:52 pts/0    00:00:00 grep nohup

which of the PIDs is PID of nohup process? The first one 8503 is always diffrent, while the second one is the same.

Comment: why not skip the grep bit and look down the list

Comment: What do you mean with skip the grep? @EdHeal

Comment: None of these is the pid of your nohup process. Your java and the nohup process seems to have exited, as they don't exist.

Comment: just run `ps -aux` and look down the list

Comment: ps nohup is not a process

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the program test.jar is finished. See output in nohup.out. To avoid to display grep as a process, use the following pattern:

```
ps -aux | grep 'j[a]va'
```

or

```
ps -aux | grep java | grep -v grep
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command in your terminal may help you out to run the script using nohup and redirect the output in your desired file.

General Syntax

```
nohup some_command &> nohup_log_file.out &
```

Example

```
nohup python script.py &> nohup_log_script.out &
```